# Feasibility of space faring centipedes

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, evolution

In the distant future, humanity has encountered, made peace and wars with countless advanced civilizations, but one civilization that still baffles them, is the race of intelligent centipedes.

The centipedes possesses multiple appendages for holding items, utilities, and tools, while the others are used for walking and other purposes. The centipedes' top shell seems to be mushy to the touch and is said to be shed off at the later stages of their life.

Other than having a striking similarity to centipedes, the species are known to eat both plants and animals and, each member of their race seems to vary in physique, much like humans.

What would cause centipedes to evolve and become a space faring race?

Comment: Organic space faring, like the Zerg, or are they technological space faring like we are?

Comment: The species is technologically space fairing, and is slightly more advanced than humanity in this scenario

Comment: I assume "she’ll" is a typo, but I cannot figure out what word is supposed to be there. Unless it is "shell", but is it a shell if it is mushy?

Answer (score 4):

If a species is intelligent and has tool-making physical capacity, there doesn't appear to be any mental barrier to going to space eventually, regardless of its physical body style. There might be a problem if its body truly cannot handle the G-force acceleration needed to escape planetary gravity.

So the real question is "what would cause centipedes to develop sentience and the ability to make tools?" Likely, the same things that drove our evolution:

1. Dumb luck to develop a language center in the brain that allows for longer memory and symbolic manipulation.
2. A competitive environment where the centipedes' survival becomes dependent upon their tactical abilities.

Once you cross that intelligence threshold, evidence suggests that the species will eventually take ownership of its evolution, shaping its environment to itself rather than itself to the environment.